Generate confusion matrix from Keras model predictions in R / RStudio
A lot of questions on exactly this on StackOverflow but all only applicable to Python (e.g. here).
I have created a keras model in R for binary classification, and would like to create a confusion matrix (true positives, true negatives, etc).
The trained model is, however, stored in a Keras history object, which I can't use predict() on using base R.
I can make predictions on my model, but I'm not sure this makes sense, as I have not yet trained that object yet, so not sure how it is making predictions.
input <- layer_input(shape = c(10, 10, 2))
output <- input %>%
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 64, kernel_size = 5, activation = "relu" %>%
  layer_dense(1, activation = "sigmoid")

mymodel <- keras_model(input, output)

mymodel %>% compile(loss = "binary_crossentropy",
                   optimizer = "rmsprop",
                   metrics = "accuracy")

callbacks <- list(
  callback_model_checkpoint(
    filepath = "convnet.tf",
    save_best_only = TRUE,
    monitor = "val_loss"
  )
)

history <- mymodel %>% fit(
  mytrainingdataset,
  epochs = 5,
  validation_data = myvalidationdataset,
  callbacks = callbacks
)

predictions <- predict(mymodel, mytestdataset)
print(predictions)

> print(predictions)
              [,1]
   [1,] 0.82142373
   [2,] 0.11238272
   [3,] 0.99224752
   [4,] 0.82643630
   [5,] 0.89288525
   [6,] 0.06666661
   [7,] 0.02123778

Is there a way to extract the trained model from the history object, make predictions, then convert those predictions to a confusion matrix in R?

Loading & saving models, including weight adjustment at certain checkpoints of the training process is described here
If you are using TensorFlow and Keras you can use the load_model_tf() and save_model_tf() procedures which are documented here. The former can also include non-Keras objects to class/functions such as custom metrics or custom loss functions which can be mapped using dict() from the reticulate package.
Regarding a confusion matrix you can use table on an object resulting from predict as shown here
From what I can see from the 2022 documentation page, it seems to depend what content was stored from the previous model that you are trying to access. If it's a complete model that needs to be resumed model <- load_model_tf('your_model/') should do the job. If only the configuration was stored (JSON), use model <- model_from_json(json_string,  custom_objects = list('your_model' = your_model_constructor)) and if model weights haven been stored, use  model <- load_model_weights_tf('your_model/')

Thanks, Growing! I've had a read through the links but am still confused unfortunately (am very new to Keras). How do I use the final version of the trained model from the Keras history object to predict on a new test dataset? I'm familiar with the table() function with non-Keras predictions in R, but can't use predict() to begin with as it doesn't recognise the trained model from the Keras history object

There used to be an easy solution to my conundrum ( https://forum.posit.co/t/how-to-predict-after-creating-keras-model-done-after-complie-fit-history/27290/5 ) but not since Tensorflow deprecated a lot of the in-built Keras predict() functions (e.g. predict_proba() )
